# plusone.js (Google) stops certain JS Scripts when logged into Google account

Tags: javascript, browser, google-plus, dom-events

I have a couple of small Javascript scripts on my website that does not load **only** when I'm logged into my Google account.

No errors are displayed (either on-site or console). The problem only appeared when I started using multiple occurrences of the Google badges (for the personal profile, community pages etc). I've got a hunch that it's due to problems with event listeners not being registered by the browser for some reason on page load?

Example problem page: http://www.festivalarchive.com/event/jakarta-international-java-jazz-festival-2014/

Problem areas:

- skyscanner widget not displaying under 'Flights & Transportation' page
- custom google map is not displaying under 'Maps & Transport Hubs' in tabbed section at bottom of the page.

The code can be seen in full on above link.

I have tried using many/all different types of Google+ badge implementation code (https://developers.google.com/+/web/badge/), note I'm only using 1 occurrence of the code and have tried in multiple positions.

Comment: Anything odd showing up in the console? (If so, might want to add it to the question.)

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant with 'no errors are displayed'. No errors in the console, everything seems to be fine. I'm not sure whether it's an issue with Chrome browser, chrome plus or javascript.... :-s